# Pagespeed and AMP

Tags: amp-html

In my website we are using the [Google Page Speed Service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service) to optimize the performance, but with amp-html im getting a few issues because PageSpeed compile all my inline style amp-custom and put in a external file and also include a js file in the end of the code which is not allowed by amp rules.

Is that any way to work with both? AMP and Google page service?

Answer (score 1):

From the link you submitted, it states that PageSpeed Service was turned off on August 3rd, 2015.  Maybe other CDNs are still using it.

It does look like there is an option for configuring what parts of your page are to be optimized.  More info is found at [Configure Rewriters](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/settings).  You can start there and disable some of the optimizations that may be creating the external CSS files.